# Query on Apache Http Server for WebDAV

Tags: apache, http, webdav

All,

I am attempting to use WebDAV ('Web-based Distributed Authoring and Versioning') functionality for Apache Http.

I have installed Http server.
The httpd.conf has been modified as

```
DavLockDB /usr/local/apache2/var/DavLock
<Directory /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/CREF>
Require all granted
Dav On

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
AuthGroupFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/groups
Require group GroupName
</Directory>
```

User/Passwords are stored in passwords file, multiple users are added under groups.

After starting the Http server, I can see the designated folder

http://{FQDN}:8080/CREF/

However when I access the above link in browser - I can see that I am able to access the directory /CREF.

I am also able to map this to a network drive in my Windows machine.

However I see the following issues

1. I am not asked to authenticate - i.e. I am not asked to enter username/password
2. I can get files out of the folder /CREF but not able to copy into the folder /CREF

Can some one review the httpd.conf changes I had mentioned above?

regards,
D